# How to test search with testcafe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I am having the following problem:
That I can't check if "search" works?

My code:

```
test('/search', async t => {
  const search = await Selector('#input').value
  await t
    .typeText('q[product_name_or_user_fullname_cont]', 'abcd')
    .click('[name="commit"]')
})
```

My page:

[image]

I want that the search bar will be checked in `testcafe`

I searched but did not know where I am wrong.
Help me
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to check the search results on the page. Use the [assertion methods](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html) to compare the actual values with expected ones.